# How to use both display inline and margins/text-align

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to create a multiplication equation in the form of 5 × 5 but since h2 tags are block-level elements, they start a new line. I tried to use display: inline and display:inline-block with margins (margin-left and margin: auto), using h2 and .equation as selectors, but it didn't do anything. Using text-align also didn't do anything. There's no float center option, so that doesn't work either. A little help?

```
<div class="equation">
    <h2 id="num1" class="num1multiply"></h2>
    <h2 id="msign">×</h2>           
    <h2 id="num2" class="num2multiply"></h2>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
h2 {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: 'inline' property accept padding and margin only two side(left and right). Use 'inline-block' element to apply all the sides.

Comment: Hi, if I try to use margin: auto, then nothing happens for some reason. That's what doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: 'margin:atuto' will work only for width specified element. In general `div` automatically gets 100% width. So `inline-block` you need to specify width and then apply margin auto.

Comment: so you need to put all these headings in one line.

Comment: what about display: flex

Comment: like this .equation {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

Comment: Thanks Suresh. So would there be no way to center headings inside the div itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to inline all the elements then `flex-box` is the best choice.
You can do so by adding it to your stylesheet.

```
.equation {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

If you don't want to use flexbox. Then `display: inline-block` with a `float` will help. The example will be.

```
h2 {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

**Note: This is for example purposes only. Don't try to apply styles directly on the `h2` tag, the style will be applied to all `h2` elements of the page**

Use it like this if you want it to apply on `h2` tags within the `.equation`

```
.equation h2 {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to use flex, but the items aren't aligned to the center.

.equation {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

Comment: wouldn't it be better to remove the margin. Set margin: 0 on all h2 elements.

Comment: The flex will work, be sure to see if the style of other elements on the page is causing issues.

Comment: Hi, there's no style conflicts. I do have a clue to what might be wrong. When I inspect element and I toggle the flexbox highlighter (press on flex next to the div tag) there's a purple pattern on the right of the box, while the part with the headings doesn't have this pattern. Does this mean anything?

Comment: if you are working on live project then i can help. but the issue isn't with flexbox anyway

Comment: I'm new lol, what does live project mean?

Comment: are you working on the local machine or on live website?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228189/discussion-between-subtrude-and-raashid-din-dar).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **h2** use label or span and set font accordingly